# Download eBay shipping charges through Excel 2010 VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to download non-free shipping charges from eBay.  I have the item numbers of the pages.  The links should go to the right pages on eBay.

While trying to go to the page and download the data, Excel hangs.

I have similar working code that gets the eBay item numbers on many pages from eBay.

If this code can't be fixed how can I get the info I need into Excel?

```
        itemNumberAlone = Range("a" & eachItem).Value
        With ActiveSheet.QueryTables.Add(Connection:= _
          "URL;http://www.ebay.com/itm/" & itemNumberAlone & "?ru=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.ebay.com%2Fsch%2Fi.html%3F_from%3DR40%26_sacat%3D0%26_nkw%3D" & itemNumberAlone & "%26_rdc%3D1" _
          , Destination:=Range("$bZ$1"))
            .Name = "second ebay links"
            .FieldNames = True
            .RowNumbers = False
            .FillAdjacentFormulas = False
            .PreserveFormatting = True
            .RefreshOnFileOpen = True
            .BackgroundQuery = True
            .RefreshStyle = xlOverwriteCells
            .SavePassword = False
            .SaveData = True
            .AdjustColumnWidth = True
            .RefreshPeriod = 0
            .WebSelectionType = xlEntirePage
            .WebFormatting = xlWebFormattingNone
            .WebPreFormattedTextToColumns = True
            .WebConsecutiveDelimitersAsOne = True
            .WebSingleBlockTextImport = False
            .WebDisableDateRecognition = False
            .WebDisableRedirections = False
            .Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
        End With

        Do While Not IsError(Application.Match("Shipping and handling", Range("bz1:bz1000"), 0))
            If IsError(Application.Match("Shipping and handling", Range("bz1:bz1000"), 0)) Then Exit Do
            If Not IsError(Application.Match("Shipping and handling", Range("bz1:bz1000"), 0)) Then
                shippingRow = Application.Match("Shipping and handling", Range("bz1:bz1000"), 0) + 1
                shippingCell = Range("bz" & shippingRow).Value
                If Left(shippingCell, 2) <> "US" Then
                    Range("bz" & shippingRow - 1).ClearContents
                Else
                    Range("c" & eachItem).Value = Right(shippingCell, Len(shippingCell) - 2)
                End If
            End If
        Loop

    End If

Next
```

Comment: I don't think this is all the code, where is eachitem defined?

Comment: I've added in the variable declarations and the code seems to work fine for me. Though I'm using Excel 2003, is that an option for you to try? Do you have any error messages you can provide? Is it possible you've been blocked by eBay?

Comment: This might help, how to troubleshoot crashes / hangs in Excel: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2758592

Answer (score 1):

I think you will have to learn DOM automation to do this cleanly. I took a look at the HTML on the ebay pages and it might be a little much for someone who hasn't used DOM automation before. I wasn't planning on writing this but it sounds like you are in a bit of a pinch, so here you go. You can use it to learn from. Just keep in mind that this will work in the short-term but when they change their HTML, it will fail.

```
Option Explicit

Sub Get_Ebay_Shipping_Charges()
Dim IE As Object, DOM_DOC As Object
Dim URL$, SHIPPING_CHARGES$
Dim SHIPPING_AMOUNT
Dim i&, x&
Dim EL, EL_COLLECTION, CHILD_NODES, TABLE_NODES, TABLE_ROW_NODES, TABLE_DATA_NODES, ITEM_NUMBER_ARRAY
Dim WS As Excel.Worksheet
Dim ITEM_NOT_FOUND As Boolean

''You should change this to the worksheet name you want to use
''ie Set WS = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Ebay")
Set WS = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1)

''Create an Internet Explorer Object
Set IE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")

''Make it visible
IE.Visible = True

''You can replace this with an array that is built from your spreadsheet, this is just for demo purposes
ITEM_NUMBER_ARRAY = Array("290941626676", "130942854921", "400035340501")

''In your code, you can start your loop here to handle the list of items
''This code is a little different for demo purposes
For x = 0 To UBound(ITEM_NUMBER_ARRAY)

    ''Here is your URL
    URL = "http://www.ebay.com/itm/" & ITEM_NUMBER_ARRAY(x) & "?ru=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.ebay.com%2Fsch%2Fi.html%3F_from%3DR40%26_sacat%3D0%26_nkw%3D" & ITEM_NUMBER_ARRAY(x) & "%26_rdc%3D1"

    ''Navigate to your URL
    IE.navigate URL

    ''This loop will wait until the page is received from the server - the page was hanging for me too so I added a counter to exit after a certain number of loops (this is the i variable)
    Do Until IE.readystate = 4 Or i = 50000
        i = i + 1
       DoEvents
    Loop
    i = 0

    ''This sets the DOM document
    Set DOM_DOC = IE.document

    ''First get a collection of table names
    Set EL_COLLECTION = DOM_DOC.GetElementsByTagName("table")
    If IsEmpty(EL_COLLECTION) Then ITEM_NOT_FOUND = True: GoTo ERR_EXIT

    ''Then look for the table classname that matches the one we want (in this case "sh-tbl") and set the childnodes to a new collection
    For Each EL In EL_COLLECTION
        If EL.ClassName = "sh-tbl" Then
            Set CHILD_NODES = EL.ChildNodes
            Exit For
        End If
    Next EL
    If IsEmpty(CHILD_NODES) Then ITEM_NOT_FOUND = True: GoTo ERR_EXIT

    ''Next look for the TBODY element in the childnodes collection and set the childnodes of the TBODY element when found
    For Each EL In CHILD_NODES

        If Not TypeName(EL) = "DispHTMLDOMTextNode" Then

            If EL.tagname = "TBODY" Then
                Set TABLE_NODES = EL.ChildNodes
                Exit For
            End If

        End If

    Next EL
    If IsEmpty(TABLE_NODES) Then ITEM_NOT_FOUND = True: GoTo ERR_EXIT

    ''Find the TR element and set its childnodes to another collection
    For Each EL In TABLE_NODES

        If Not TypeName(EL) = "DispHTMLDOMTextNode" Then

            If EL.tagname = "TR" Then
                Set TABLE_ROW_NODES = EL.ChildNodes
                Exit For
            End If

         End If

    Next EL
    If IsEmpty(TABLE_ROW_NODES) Then ITEM_NOT_FOUND = True: GoTo ERR_EXIT

    ''Find the first TD element and get it's childnodes
    For Each EL In TABLE_ROW_NODES

        If Not TypeName(EL) = "DispHTMLDOMTextNode" Then

            If EL.tagname = "TD" Then
                Set TABLE_DATA_NODES = EL.ChildNodes
                Exit For
            End If

        End If

     Next EL
     If IsEmpty(TABLE_DATA_NODES) Then ITEM_NOT_FOUND = True: GoTo ERR_EXIT

     ''The first DIV element holds the shipping information so when it is found, get the innertext of that element
     For Each EL In TABLE_DATA_NODES

        If Not TypeName(EL) = "DispHTMLDOMTextNode" Then

            If EL.tagname = "DIV" Then
                SHIPPING_CHARGES = EL.INNERTEXT
                Exit For
            End If

         End If

     Next EL

    ''Make sure a shipping charge was found
    If SHIPPING_CHARGES = vbNullString Then MsgBox "No shipping charges found for item " & ITEM_NUMBER_ARRAY(x): GoTo ERR_EXIT

    If IsNumeric(Right(SHIPPING_CHARGES, InStr(SHIPPING_CHARGES, Chr(36)))) Then
        SHIPPING_AMOUNT = Right(SHIPPING_CHARGES, InStr(SHIPPING_CHARGES, Chr(36)))
    Else
        SHIPPING_AMOUNT = SHIPPING_CHARGES
    End If

    ''You may have to change this to fit your spreadsheet
    WS.Cells(x + 1, 3).Value = SHIPPING_AMOUNT

ERR_EXIT:
        If ITEM_NOT_FOUND = True Then MsgBox "No Page Was Found For Item " &   ITEM_NUMBER_ARRAY(x): ITEM_NOT_FOUND = False

Next x

IE.Quit
Set IE = Nothing

End Sub
```

If you are stuck on using your existing code, you can also try deleting the querytables after the query.

```
Dim QRY_TABLE As QueryTable

For Each QRY_TABLE In ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).QueryTables
    QRY_TABLE.Delete
Next
```

This method will not delete the querytable values on your spreadsheet but it will kill the querytable connection. If you have too many of these, it could create a crash.

One final suggestion, if your workbook contains a lot of `vlookups` then this is probably the true culprit. Good Luck!

Answer (score 1):

You can use xmlHTTP object which will download the data easier and wont make the excel stuck.

```
Sub xmlHttp()
    Dim xmlHttp As Object
    Set xmlHttp = CreateObject("MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP.6.0")

    Dim ITEM_NUMBER_ARRAY As Variant
    ITEM_NUMBER_ARRAY = Array("290941626676", "130942854921", "400035340501")
    For x = 0 To UBound(ITEM_NUMBER_ARRAY)

        ''Here is your URL
        URL = "http://www.ebay.com/itm/" & ITEM_NUMBER_ARRAY(x) & "?ru=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.ebay.com%2Fsch%2Fi.html%3F_from%3DR40%26_sacat%3D0%26_nkw%3D" & ITEM_NUMBER_ARRAY(x) & "%26_rdc%3D1"

        xmlHttp.Open "GET", URL, False
        xmlHttp.setRequestHeader "Content-Type", "text/xml"
        xmlHttp.send


        Dim html As Object
        Set html = CreateObject("htmlfile")

        html.body.innerHTML = xmlHttp.ResponseText
        Set objShipping = html.getelementbyid("shippingSection").getElementsbytagname("td")(0)


        If Not objShipping Is Nothing Then
            Set divShip = objShipping.ChildNodes(1)
            Debug.Print divShip.innerHTML
            Else
            Debug.Print "No Data"
        End If

    Next
End Sub
```

**Immediate Window (Ctrl + G)**

US $2.55 
No Data
US $6.50

[image]

Comment: I prefer using the `xmlhttp` object over DOM as well but I believe the OP is trying to get the "Shipping and Handling" charge, not the item price. The "Shipping and Handling" charge does not have an element id so I decided to go with DOM in my solution instead. You could still do it with `xmlhttp` as well but I figured it would be just as lengthy to parse out the right nodes (although I could be wrong).

Comment: @UberNubIsTrue I mis-understood the question. Thanks for pointing out. I have updated the code and hope its what needed.

Comment: Very nice, I like your solution a lot better than the one I wrote. Way cleaner. +1